# Forcing Bootstrap 3 mobile layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 layout in my Wordpress site and the loop brings in 2 different templates for my posts.

type 1

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h3>sub</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <p>stuff</p>
    </div>       
</div>
```

type 2

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <p>stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h3>sub</h3>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Basically some posts have content on the left, others have it on the right. All the posts are stacked on top of each other.

On mobiles, I want the col-md-4 to always go under col-md-8. By default Bootstrap puts second div under the first. So on type 2 versions it works fine. But I need it do it on type 1 versions as well. (I need to keep col-md-8 on the left, and col-md-4 on the right in type 1 versions in screen sizes though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder your columns for certain screen sizes. Assuming you want to make cols full size and reorder them for sm screen sizes, type 1 would have to look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-push-12 col-md-4">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h3>sub</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-12 col-md-8">
      <p>stuff</p>
    </div>       
</div>
```

For more info, read on here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: the posts basically have small content column on the right or left. Problem is that when the small column is on the left then the big one gets pushed underneath. Will your code still put one beside the other on big screens?

Comment: your code didn't exactly work, but the link you provided gave me the answer I needed, thank you

Comment: I didn't have all information about your exact scenario so I just wrote what I believed would give you an idea about column ordering. Good to hear I could point you into the right direction.